# no member named 'dynamic_cast_tag' in namespace boost::detail (SALOME 7.3.0)

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, dynamic-cast

I am trying to compile SALOME 7.3.0 on OSX Mavericks (Darwin 13.0.0) and have boost 1.55 installed (using homebrew). GCC chokes on one of the toolkit functions from SALOME (SRC/DF) when trying to define a template function the error is:

```
    In file included from /Users/dingram/Developer/SALOME/KERNEL_SRC_7.3.0/src/DF/DF_Attribute.cxx:20:
/Users/dingram/Developer/SALOME/KERNEL_SRC_7.3.0/src/DF/DF_definitions.hxx:50:44: error: no member named 'dynamic_cast_tag' in namespace
      'boost::detail'
     boost::shared_ptr<T>(r,boost::detail::dynamic_cast_tag())
                                           ^
```

the code fragment is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

template<class T> class df_shared_ptr: public boost::shared_ptr<T>
{
public:
  df_shared_ptr() {}

  template<class Y>
    explicit df_shared_ptr(Y * p)
      {
        boost::shared_ptr<T>::reset(p);
      }

  template<class Y>
    df_shared_ptr(df_shared_ptr<Y> const & r):
     boost::shared_ptr<T>(r,boost::detail::dynamic_cast_tag())
        {}
```

I am not a C++ programmer and so am more than a little stymied. There are reports of similar problems on the SALOME forums but no replies.

Comment: looks like a missing include. FYI, it's not recommended to use the members of the details namespace directly.

Answer (score 1):

A recent change to the boost library eliminated boost::detail::dynamic_cast_tag() in favor of a new mechanism for dynamic casting.  The documentation for this is poor to non-existent.

You should be able to build with an older boost, I think 1.44 should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. editing the source and using dynamic_pointer_cast<> solved the issue. In this case:

```
  boost::shared_ptr<T>(r,boost::detail::dynamic_cast_tag())
```

becomes

```
  boost::shared_ptr<T>(dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(r))
```